# MongoDB SELECT REPLACE in project query

Tags: mongodb, select, replace, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My MySQL table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table_1` (`id`, `name`, `status`, `date_added`) VALUES
(1, 'CNN', 1, '2018-07-01 00:00:01'),
(2, 'BBC', 1, '2018-07-03 00:00:01');
```

My MySQL Query is this

```
SELECT REPLACE(name, 'C','A') as name FROM `table_1` order by name ASC
```

SQL result is this:

```
Name:
ANN
BBC
```

My mongodb table is this:

```
db.table_1.insertMany( [
 { id: "1", name: "CNN", status: true, date_added: '2018-07-01 00:00:01' },
 { id: "2", name: "BBC",  status: true, date_added: '2018-07-03 00:00:01' }
]);
```

I am trying with aggregation as follows:

```
db.table_1.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        _id:true,
        name:true
    }
    },

])
```

I want the output ANN, BBC. here CNN should be converted to ANN

Answer (score 0):

Good question. MongoDB doesn't provide an operator to this but this is doable with the following aggregation pipeline. :)

However, I would suggest you do this client side.

```
[
   {
      "$addFields": {
         "newName": {
            "$reduce": {
               "input": {
                  "$map": {
                     "input": {
                        "$range": [
                           0,
                           {
                              "$strLenCP":"$name"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "in": {
                        "$let": {
                           "vars": {
                              "char": {
                                 "$toLower": {
                                    "$substrCP": [
                                       "$name",
                                       "$$this",
                                       1
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "in": {
                              "$cond": [
                                 {
                                    "$eq": [
                                       "$$char",
                                       "c"
                                    ]
                                 },
                                 "A",
                                 {
                                    "$toUpper":"$$char"
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "initialValue":"",
               "in": {
                  "$concat": [
                     "$$value",
                     "$$this"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: why mongodb doesn't have a simple query to do this just like sql does?

Comment: I have no idea, I hope future release will provide this. As I mentioned OP is better off doing this on client side. I posted this answer for learning purpose. @AnthonyWinzlet